# Mix and transform the original Bootstrap colors to obtain a known color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, less

Maybe the question is absurde but I'm currently implementing a project in Twitter Bootstrap and I would mantain the original colors of the framework. So, if I want to add another color, I would use the power of Less and its functions to mix and transform original colors of Bootstrap to obtain the color I need.

This is the Bootstrap original colors:

```
@gray-base:         #000;
@gray-darker:       lighten(@gray-base, 13.5%); // #222
@gray-dark:         lighten(@gray-base, 20%);   // #333
@gray:              lighten(@gray-base, 33.5%); // #555
@gray-light:        lighten(@gray-base, 46.7%); // #777
@gray-lighter:      lighten(@gray-base, 93.5%); // #eee

@brand-primary:     #428bca;
@brand-success:     #5cb85c;
@brand-info:        #5bc0de;
@brand-warning:     #f0ad4e;
@brand-danger:      #d9534f;
```

Suppose that I want to obtain the color `#4FA293`. To do this I use the Less function `mix()` like this:

```
mix(#428bca, #5cb85c, 50%)
```

where `#428bca` is `@brand-primary` color and `#5cb85c` is `@brand-success` color.

This is only an example to understand my target. The question is:

is there a tool that mix, converts and transforms the Bootstrap colors to obtain an a priori known color?

Is there a mathematical relationship to achieve that?

I suppose that I can obtain all of colors starting from the 5 Bootrasp colors and the less functions.

Comment: Why can you not reassign the variables with the colors you want? `@brand-primary: #4FA293`? Notice that Less uses last declaration wins for variables

Comment: Also check projects like http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/ and http://rriepe.github.io/1pxdeep/

Comment: I need the Bootstrap set of colors. Now, how can I add a new color to the set? Can I generate new colors from the Bootstrap set? If not, can I add a custom color with hover, buttons, navs, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the Bootstrap set of colors. Now, how can I add a new color to
>   the set? Can I generate new colors from the Bootstrap set? If not, can
>   I add a custom color with hover, buttons, navs, etc.?

Well defining a new addition color is easy: `@brand-custom: #4FA293`. To apply that color on component you should use the Bootstrap mixins (also read : http://bassjobsen.weblogs.fm/adding-background-gradient-bootstraps-navbar-less/).

Example button:

```
@brand-custom: #4FA293;
.btn-custom {
  .button-variant(#fff; @brand-custom; darken(@brand-custom, 5%));
}
```

You can write down the preceding code at the end of the bootstrap.less file. After recompiling you are able to use:

```
<button class="btn btn-custom">Custom button</button>
```

The button now should look as follows:

[image]

Than you can do the same to customize your panels:

```
.panel-custom {
  .panel-variant(darken(spin(@brand-custom, -10), 7%); #fff;  @brand-custom; darken(spin(@brand-custom, -10), 7%););
}
```

Now the following panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

Will looks like that shown below:

[image]

When inspecting Bootstrap's [variables.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/variables.less) file, you should notice that the original panel colors are not directly derived from the brand colors ([one could wonder why not](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14840)).

The CSS code for the success panel has been created with the following mixin:

```
.panel-success {
  .panel-variant(@panel-success-border; @panel-success-text; @panel-success-heading-bg; @panel-success-border);
}
```

With the variables defined as follows:

```
@state-success-text:          #3c763d;
@state-success-bg:            #dff0d8;
@state-success-border:        darken(spin(@state-success-bg, -10), 5%);
@panel-success-text:          @state-success-text;
@panel-success-border:        @state-success-border;
@panel-success-heading-bg:    @state-success-bg;
```

So changing `@brand-success` does not change the `.panel-success` CSS class.

You should repeat the above steps or each component that you would set with the `@brand-custom` color.

Comment: Thank you so much Bass, it's great! Do you know a tool to obtain the less functions and mixin starting from @brand-custom? I will add the code to variable.less file.

Comment: AFAIK there no such tool. You should download Bootstrap source code at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/. Than you will find the button mixins in less/buttons.less, the panel mixins in less/panels.less and so on